# Reviewing a question that doesn't belong

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, editing

There is [currently a question on hold](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68472/how-to-only-allow-3-values-in-a-if-and-while-statement-to-allow-the-loop-to#), which really should never have been posted to Code Review, but I think it actually highlights a point that would be worth an answer.

I started to edit the question to fix the OP's mistake, and voted to reopen, but after thinking about it, I don't think that was right, so I reverted my change.

The OP is probably long gone (he had asked basically the same question on SO, which I answered if he cares enough to check back).

Should a question, which the poster doesn't really want to be reviewed (and thus doing so is of no use to him at least), be reviewed?

Answer (score 11):

Your instincts are good. The question was off-topic because the code did not work. Therefore, the only way to make it on-topic would be to edit the code, which is [forbidden](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/should-you-edit-someone-elses-code-in-a-question). (Well, you could also [relax the goal of the code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2559/9357) to declare that it "works", but I don't see how that is possible in this case.)

Note that if you were to fix the code, it would cease to be the original poster's own code, and thus be off-topic for a different reason.

Comment: The answer I wanted to give, was about how loops should be constructed and seperating functionality/concerns -- so relaxinging the goal would have worked, but the question was already closed at that point.